# ML.Net object detection and bounding boxes

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, ml.net

I have created an image classification model using the Microsoft model builder. Now I need to use that model to detect objects in a video stream and draw bounding boxes once the object is detected. I can not find a c# sample that uses the generated model from the model builder. All samples of object detection use ONNX models. I have not found a tool to convert the model.zip generated for model builder to model.onnx.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The image classification in the model builder cannot detect object in images - it is a different problem.

What you can do is to combine the ONNX sample of object detection in images, with your own custom model.

Basically you run the onnx sample up until the parsing of the bounding boxes. Then you run that part of the image through your image classifier and use that label instead.

It is somewhat of a hack, and you will have a hard time getting anywhere near realtime performance.

ONNX sample for ONNX detection:
https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/DeepLearning_ObjectDetection_Onnx

Comment: Thank you very much Karl. That  is what  I have been trying. But when I get  to the part where the Onnx sample use the model and I need to replace it with mine (ML.Net model). I an not sure how to do it and I have not seen a similar sample.